# Add unpacked json data to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an initial df that looks like:

| id | title | urls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | title1 | [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com) |
| 2 | title2 | [www.url2.com](http://www.url2.com) |

I would like to use `apply` or some loop that can take each row and after an api call unpack a json blob into new column data for each row...

```
for r in df:
    json_blob = make_api_call(r.urls)
    # take json blob and put into df?
    pd.read_json(json_blob)
    # add to row r back in the original df?
```

Such that given the api data ->

```json
{
  "validThrough": "2022-10-16",
  "description": "this and that",
  "Location": {
    "geo": {
      "longitude": "-73.962547",
      "latitude": "40.687089",
      "@type": "GeoCoordinates"
    }
}
```

df after everything ->

|  | title | urls | validThrough | description | Location.geo.longitude | Location.geo.latitude | Location.geo.@type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | title1 | [www.url1.com](http://www.url1.com) | 2022-10-16 | this is a description | -73.962547 | 40.687089 | GeoCoordinates |
| n | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: Use pandas.json_normalize.

Comment: That does not solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Solved this with

```py
def get_api_data(url):
   json_data = make_req(url)
   # returns a series that apply can use
   return pd.json_normalize(job_info).squeeze()

df1 = df.apply(lambda x: get_api_data(x['url']), axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```